# Positioning-related problem with dropdown menu in a horizontal navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a simple horizontal navigation bar using html, css and javascript. The navigation bar contains a dropdown menu (named More). Clicking on the More menu causes hidden links to be shown (vertically) beneath the More heading, and clicking again causes the links to be hidden again.

I tried setting the positions of the navigation bar element and More menu element to be "relative" in the css code, and set the position of the hidden links element to be "absolute", also in the css code. However, when I then clicked on the More menu, it didn't show the hidden links. Nothing happened. But if I comment out the "relative" positioning of both the navigation bar and More menu, clicking on the More menu works (the hidden links are shown).

I've included the buggy code (html, css and javascript).

Why doesn't the buggy code display the hidden links when clicking on More?

Thanks, Mfl.

```js
function clickMoreMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hiddenlinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#navbar { 
  margin : 0; padding : 0; 
  background : Pink; overflow : hidden;    
  position : relative;  
} 

.navoption { float : left; }  

#moremenu {
  position: relative;
  display : inline-block; 
  background : Pink; 
}

#hiddenlinks {
  display: none;
  position : absolute; 
  z-index : 1;
  background : Pink; 
}

div a {
  display : block; text-align : center; 
  text-decoration : none; color : Black; 
  padding : 10px; 
} 


div a.current {background : HotPink; } 

div a:hover { background : DeepPink; color : White; }
```

```html
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Test Navigation Bar Page</title>
    <link href="testnav.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />   
</head>

<body>

<div id = "navbar"> 

<div class="navoption"> <a href="option1.html">Option 1</a> </div> 
<div class="navoption"> <a href="option2.html">Option 2</a> </div> 
<div class="navoption"> <a href="option3.html">Option 3</a> </div> 

<div class="navoption" id = "moremenu"> 
    <div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickMoreMenu()">More</a> </div> 
    <div id = "hiddenlinks">
        <a href="option4.html">Option 4</a> 
        <a href="option5.html">Option 5</a> 
        <a href="option6.html">Option 6</a>  
    </div>
</div> 

</div> 

<h1>Test Navigation Bar Page</h1>

<script src="moremenu.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set overflow of #navbar, which makes your hiddenlinks invisible simply because they are not fitting in.

A possible solution is not using overflow hidden:

```js
function clickMoreMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hiddenlinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#navbar { 
  margin : 0; padding : 0; 
  background : Pink; 
  position : relative;  
  display: flex;
} 

.navoption { float : left; }  

#moremenu {
  position: relative;
  display : inline-block; 
  background : Pink; 
}

#hiddenlinks {
  display: none;
  position : absolute; 
  z-index : 1;
  background : Pink; 
}

div a {
  display : block; text-align : center; 
  text-decoration : none; color : Black; 
  padding : 10px; 
} 


div a.current {background : HotPink; } 

div a:hover { background : DeepPink; color : White; }
```

```html
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Test Navigation Bar Page</title>
    <link href="testnav.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />   
</head>

<body>

<div id = "navbar"> 

<div class="navoption"> <a href="option1.html">Option 1</a> </div> 
<div class="navoption"> <a href="option2.html">Option 2</a> </div> 
<div class="navoption"> <a href="option3.html">Option 3</a> </div> 

<div class="navoption" id = "moremenu"> 
    <div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickMoreMenu()">More</a> </div> 
    <div id = "hiddenlinks">
        <a href="option4.html">Option 4</a> 
        <a href="option5.html">Option 5</a> 
        <a href="option6.html">Option 6</a>  
    </div>
</div> 

</div> 

<h1>Test Navigation Bar Page</h1>

<script src="moremenu.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add `position: relative` to either `#navbar` or `#moremenu` `#hiddenlinks` remains hidden regardless of the display rules you add to it because of the `overflow: hidden` rule you added to `#navbar`.

The `overflow: hidden` rule will clip the content of the element when it's too big to fit its [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context). The box formatting context is a region set by the display property of the element.

When you set `position: relative` to either `#navbar` or `#moremenu`, `#hiddenlinks` is considered part of the content inside of #navbar. And because it is outside the box formatting context it hides it.

When you remove the relative positioning for both `#navbar` and `#moremenu`, `#hiddenlinks` is no longer considered part of the content of `#navbar` and hence not clipped or hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I have a related question. If I just delete `overflow : hidden;` from `#navbar`, the heading ("Test Navigation Bar Page") appears to the right of the navigation bar, but if I add `display : flex;` to `#navbar`, as suggested by the first person to answer my question, the heading appears below the navigation bar. Why is this?

Comment: @mfl1971 because you have float: left on your .navoption

Comment: @mfl1971 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float